# How do you filter to get data that is in between a certain time of day in IBM DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to add a filter condition in the DB2 database.  I am new to it and come from an Oracle background.  I am trying to get records with dates in between today at 4 AM and today at 5 PM only.  I currently have the below query that returns zero results:

```
db2 => select datetimeColumn from datetimeExample WHERE datetimeColumn  BETWEEN timestamp(current date) - 1 day + 4 hour AND timestamp(current date) - 1 day + 13 hour

DATETIMECOLUMN
--------------------------

0 record(s) selected.
```

And here is the data in the table that I believe should show but there is something wrong with condition statement, any help is appreciated

```
db2 => select * from datetimeExample

DATETIMECOLUMN
--------------------------
2016-06-16-09.38.53.759000
1988-12-25-17.12.30.000000
2016-12-25-17.10.30.000000
2016-06-16-04.10.30.000000
2016-06-16-05.10.30.000000
1988-12-25-15.12.30.000000
1988-12-25-14.12.30.000000
2016-06-16-12.10.30.000000
2016-06-16-07.10.30.000000
2016-06-16-08.10.30.000000

10 record(s) selected.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query should work when you leave out the `- 1 day`. The reason is that `timestamp(current date)` returns the timestamp for today at zero hours. Then you add 4 hours and are at the required start time. Similar maths for the end time (and 5 pm should be `+ 17 hours`).

```
select datetimeColumn from datetimeExample
WHERE datetimeColumn  
BETWEEN timestamp(current date) + 4 hours AND timestamp(current date) + 17 hours
```

Comment: This will get wrong results sometimes, the upper bound should be exclusive (`<`).  [This post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) talks about SQL Server, but the problem is really about how numbers and values are represented.

Comment: "Wrong results" in this case probably depends on whether the inclusive nature of BETWEEN AND is understood for DATEs/TIMEs/TIMESTAMPs or not. I've always expected the endpoints to be included.